# Sort by length (3rd column)

Tags: cygwin

I'm trying to sort the 3rd column by length (short > long).

I have 3 tables, split between 2 delimiters.

Example: Stack:A:Overflow

I want to sort it by length of the 3rd column (i have thousands of lines).

Answer (score 1):

With a bit of scripting:

`awk -F: '{print length($3), $0}' filename | sort -n | cut -d ' ' -f 1 --complement`

(Note that this is not Cygwin-specific.)